# is it possible to output the verbose info when using pnpm update

Tags: typescript, pnpm

I am using this pnpm command to update the node dependencies:

```
pnpm update
```

is it possible to output the udpate verbose information? I have tried this command:

```
pnpm update --verbose
```

and also tried like this:

```
pnpm update --debug
```

both did not work. This is the pnpm version info:

```
> pnpm version
npm info using npm@9.6.7
npm info using node@v16.14.2
{
  'texhub-web': '0.1.0',
  npm: '9.6.7',
  node: '16.14.2',
  v8: '9.4.146.24-node.20',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.45.1',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '1.1.1n+quic',
  cldr: '40.0',
  icu: '70.1',
  tz: '2021a3',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}
npm info ok
```